# Can we convert PDF, Excel, Word to Image in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, pdf, doc

In my project, there is a requirement to convert PDF, Excel, Word documents to images.

I know there is imagemagick can be used for conversion of PDF, but I am not sure of Excel and PDF files.

I have seen [JODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter) which converts Excel, Word etc to PDF and then I have to convert PDF to image. I dont think there is a gem or plugin in Ruby which binds JODConverter.

Is there any better solutions than these in Ruby on Rails platform?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gem [rmagick](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick) to convert pdf files to images.

Here is the sample code which will save all the pages as images in variable pdf_image.

```
pdf_image = Magick::ImageList.new('tmp/prakhar.pdf'){ self.density = 150 }
```

Then you can loop around the variable pdf_image and save pages.

```
# Write the image files in the tmp/images folder
    pdf_image.each_with_index do |page, index|
      page.write('tmp/images' + '/page_' + index.to_s + '.jpg')
    end
```